jquery lightgallery data-download-url not working
I am successfully using jQuery lightGallery to show images, using version 2.8.0-beta.
The original image file leaf-names are non-descriptive such as 001.jpg, 002.jpg etc.
I would like people to be able to download the images, but with a descriptive filename such as LW-0408-001.jpg
The suggested method is to include data-download-url='LW-0408-001.jpg' but that's not working for me.
Here's my code:
<div id='0408,1' class='item' data-src='/library/pics/14/8900/larger/001.jpg' data-lg-size='1000-687' data-download-url='LW-0408-001.jpg' >
  <img id='first-image' class='landscape' src='/library/pics/14/8900/midsize/001.jpg' width="400" height="274">
</div>

But it's not working as expected. In practice, the offered filename is xxx.html
Have I misunderstood the instructions?

SOLVED!
Yes I did misunderstand the instructions. Instead of
data-download-url='LW-0408-001.jpg' it should be data-download='LW-0408-001.jpg'
